# ExtJS 5 - Download file from POST servlet request

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, ria, extjs5

I have trying to implement the export functionality in ExtJS 5 using form submit method. And I had look at the following stackoverflow link, it helps but not fully.

[Extjs 4 (with a code for 3.4 below) downloading a file returned from a post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782856/extjs-4-downloading-a-file-returned-from-a-post-request)

In my case i facing an issue after the request response is successful, getting invalid JSON encoding error.Even i tried to change the reader from JSON reader to some other string reader(mentioned in link), but it is quite successful for some reason.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?86704-handling-xml-response-on-form-submit

**Code:-**

```
  var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
    timeout: 60000
  });
  var basicForm = form.getForm();
  basicForm.errorReader= new String();
    basicForm.submit({
        url     :  GRID_EXPORT_URL,
        method  : 'POST',
        headers : {
            "USER": user,
            "SERVERSESSIONID": serverSessionId,
            "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },  
        params  : {
            gridId:"dummyGrid",
            colDescs:"col1,Name"
        },              
        scope   : this,
        success : function(responseText){              
        },
        target: '_blank' 
    });
```

**Error Message:-**

```
   [E] Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: Code
```

**Output response from Java servlet(CSV):-**

```
    Id,Name
    13092,Thiru
    12767,Arasu
    117,Vinod
```

I think because of this encoding issue,even after the request returns 200 success status; the browser download window is not getting poped up! You help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

I have modified the code something like below, but still the browser download is not happening event though the response is 200.

**Modified code with Iframe/Form:-**

```
onClickExport : function(){
    var body = Ext.getBody();
    var downloadFrame = body.createChild({
         tag: 'iframe',
         cls: 'x-hidden',
         id: 'app-upload-frame',
         name: 'uploadframe'
     });      
    var downloadForm = body.createChild({
         tag: 'form',
         cls: 'x-hidden',
         id: 'app-upload-form',
         target: 'app-upload-frame'
     });        
    Ext.Ajax.request ({
      url     : EXPORT_URL,
      method  : 'POST',
      form    : downloadForm,       
      timeout : 30 * 60 * 1000, // 30 Minutes should be OK.
      scope   : this,
      headers : {
            "USER": user,
            "SERVERSESSIONID": serverSessionId,
            "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },  
      params  : {
            gridId:"dummyGrid",
            colDescs:"col1,Name"
      }, 
      success : function (r) {
        alert("Success");
      },
      failure: function(r) {
        alert('error');
      }
    });
```

Note: I'm using Google Chrome browser!

Thanks!

Comment: Does your Java servlet return the file properly when you try with another client ? (such as Advanced REST Client for Chrome)

Comment: Yeah yes it is Francis!

Comment: Have a look: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?153253-How-to-download-a-file-using-Ext.Ajax-using-a-POST-call  I think you'll need an IFRAME.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme: I tried to add a iframe/form, but still the browser popup is not happening. Modified and added the same code above!

Comment: Can someone help me here to address this issue, please?

Comment: The fact that you get this JSON decode error without your handlers even trying tells me you may have an override somewhere. Debug the handlers and see when the error is happening exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

export can be achieved with ajax call, creating a Blob out of the response and saving using msSaveBlob. this works in modern browsers ie10 and above

```
onClickExport: function() {
    CUIF.Ajax.request({
        url: '......',
        method: 'POST',
        scope: this,
        params: {
           ...
           ...
         },
        success: function(data,response) {
            this.onExportSuccess(response);
        }
    });
},

onExportSuccess: function(response){
     this.getView().unmask("Loading...");
     var disposition = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
     var filename = disposition.slice(disposition.indexOf("=")+1,disposition.length);
     var type = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
     var blob = new Blob([response.responseText], { type: type });
     if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
        // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
     } 
     else {
        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        if (filename) {
            // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            // safari doesn't support this yet
            a.href = downloadUrl;
            a.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        } 
        setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
    }    
}
```

Comment: This works great in Chrome. But I am looking for a solution in IE 9. If you could help me with that as well!!

Comment: Hi , instead of rest URL in url , can i use ext direct url ( @ExtDirectMethod(ExtDirectMethodType.SIMPLE))  ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any headers configuration for the response?

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
// Disable caching
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies
```

Comment: All the headers where added to the servlet request, it is not happening only in ExtJS(migration framework). It is still working fine with our current Tibco GI RIA framework.  `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Mar 2015 12:41:53 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: attachment; fileName=Report_RETRIEVECHARACTERISTICTYPE_1426250513346.csv
SESSIONLOGID: 24407011
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1`

Answer (score 0):

Create a Sencha OnPostDownloader component like this using invisible form and 0 height iframe.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.OnPostDownload', {
  extend: 'Ext.Component',
  alias: 'widget.OnPostDownloader',
  autoEl: {
    tag: 'iframe',
    cls: 'x-hidden',
    src: Ext.SSL_SECURE_URL
  },
  postAndDownload: function (config) {
    var invsibleForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
      title: 'invsibleForm',
      standardSubmit: true,
      url: config.url,
      timeout: 120000,
      height: 0,
      width: 0,
      hidden: true,
      items: [ {
        xtype: 'hiddenfield',
        name: 'mydata',
        value: config.params
      } ]
    });

    invsibleForm.getForm().submit();
  }
});
```